# target="_blank" not working in (blogspot) blogger.com

Tags: url, anchor, blogger

I have used following code in my blog, on blogspot.in, so that the link should open in a new tab.

```
click <a href="http://amauryablogs.blogspot.in/2016/06/invisible-network-description.html" target="_blank">here</a>
```

Same can be verified by looking at the source code of the [page](http://amauryablogs.blogspot.in/2016/06/power-of-invisibility-illustration.html), see the link in the first paragraph. But the link is opening in the same page. This cannot be a browser's problem because I am able to use [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target) which demonstrates opening a link in a new tab. What is wrong?

Comment: There is a `mousedown` even that is changing the default behavior. It's likely being done by Blogger. I have no idea how to stop blogger from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [source](http://www.technotraps.com/open-external-links-new-tab/), you should:

- Go to your blogger dashboard
- Select your blog >> Template
- Backup your template before editing
- Click on “Edit HTML”
- Find `</head>` tag in HTML
- Add the following piece of code just above the `</head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[href^='http://']").each(
            function(){
                if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
                    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
                }
        });
        $("a[href^='https://']").each(
            function(){
                if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
                    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

- Save your Template.

Comment: Btw should that code make every link open in a new tab, or just the ones with target="_blank" ?